# Using a variable when specifying formatting options in string.format

Tags: lua

I am trying to write a function that produces a string of a fixed length. There are two cases I think I need to consider:

1. The string is too long and must be cropped
2. The string is too short and must be padded with whitespace

To do this, I have written the following:

```lua
foo = "testtesttesttest"
bar = "test"

function fixed_width_a(s)
  return string.format("%-6s", string.sub(s, 1, 6))
end

print(fixed_width_a(foo))
print(fixed_width_a(bar))

-- testte
-- test__ (Using underscores to denote spaces)
```

While I don't know if this is the best way, it works. Great!

Now, I'd like to be able to specify the width of the string as a parameter. For example,

```lua
function fixed_width_b(s, w)
  w = w or 6
  return string.format("%-ws", string.sub(s, 1, w))
end
```

Of course, this naive attempt doesn't work because "%-ws" isn't parsed correctly. Another attempt might be to specify,

```lua
string.format("%-{%d}s", w, string.sub(s, 1, w))
```

but obviously this makes no sense either.

Question: how do I specify formatting options using a variable in `string.format`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(("%-_._s"):gsub("_", 6):format("teststring"))

print(("%-"+6+"."+"s"):format("teststring"))

print(("%%-%d.%ds"):format(6,6):format("teststring"))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any reason to choose one over another or is it just a matter taste?

Comment: in the end you just have to build that format string somehow. that's just a matter of taste as it is unlikely to have any performance impact. I would probably define a function that takes the number of characters and returns the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this seems to work okay, although I don't know if it's the best option.

```lua
function fixed_width_b(s, w)
  w = w or 6
  tmp = string.format("%%-%ds", w)
  return string.format(tmp, string.sub(s, 1, w))
end
```

Here, I construct the first argument to the crop/pad part of the code as a string called `tmp`. If `w = 5`, for example, then `tmp = "%-5s"`.

---

##### Edit

For brevity, I suppose I could just write,

```lua
function fixed_width_b(s, w)
  w = w or 6
  return string.format(string.format("%%-%ds", w), string.sub(s, 1, w))
end
```

and avoid an intermediate variable.